# UICollectionView in UILabel sizeToFit

Tags: uilabel, uicollectionview, sizetofit

I used CustomCellClass in UICollectionView. Try this class in uilabel sizeToFit but not working.

But create the new uilabel in cellForItemAtIndexPath method, working.

How to set SizeToFit UICollectionView in CustomCellClass UILabel;

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Pop it in the CustomCellClass `layoutSubviews`.